# dynamic multilevel bootstrap menu with pdo and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, pdo, content-management-system

I have one db with 2 tables for main menu items and submenu items.  I was trying to implement a dynamic menu with a bootstrap theme I made, but I can't seem to understand how to merge the PHP with the HTML.  Every tutorial talks about array, but that doesn't seem reasonable with how (code) heavy a bootstrap theme can get. I'd like to be able to do that if anyone can point me in the right direction, but the first obstacle I need to overcome is the primary menu not displaying with the code I have posted. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

```
      catch(PDOException $e) { 
       echo $e->getMessage(); 
  }   
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM menu ORDER BY id";
       $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
       $stmt->execute();
 ?>
                        <ul>
                        <?php
                    while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
                        $sub_sql = "SELECT * FROM sub_menu WHERE sub_parent_id=:id";
                        $sub_stmt = $pdo->prepare($sub_sql); 
                        $sub_stmt->bindParam(':id', $row->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                        $sub_stmt->execute();                   
                        ?>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo $row->menu_name; ?>"></a>
                        <?php
                        if($sub_stmt->rowCount()){
                          ?>
                            <ul>
                            <?php
                             while ($sub_row = $sub_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
                          ?>
                          <li><a href="<?php echo $sub_row->href; ?>">
                          <?php echo $sub_row->sub_name; ?>"
                          </a></li>
                          <?php
                             }
                             ?>
                        </ul>
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>

                  </li>  
                 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM menu ORDER BY id";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
 ?>
    <ul>
    <?php
    while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
        $sub_sql = "SELECT * FROM sub_menu WHERE sub_parent_id=:id";
        $sub_stmt = $pdo->prepare($sub_sql);
        $sub_stmt->bindParam(':id', $row->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sub_stmt->execute();
        ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $row->menu_name; ?>"></a>
            <?php
            if($sub_stmt->rowCount()){
            ?>
                <ul>
                <?php
                    while ($sub_row = $sub_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
                ?>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo $sub_row->href; ?>">
                        <?php echo $sub_row->sub_name; ?>"
                    </a></li>
                <?php
                    }
                ?>
                </ul>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </li>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: No, still not working.  I am getting this in my error messages:  expects at least 2 parameters, 0 given

Comment: That was the full error message.  I used an @ script to display any errors during production and that's what it's telling me.  Seems like the prepared statement needs two parameters, but I'm sure I have at least one in there (yeah...I'm a noob).

Comment: which line you got error is either selecting `menu` or `sub menu`?